# javascript string.replace not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to dynamically replace a sub string in a parent string. I've tried string.replace('old','new') to no avail.

Here's the snippet giving me trouble.

```
newbuffer.replace( matches[i], p.shortcodes[x].vala );
console.log( "Replace " + matches[i] + " with " + p.shortcodes[x].vala );
```

Result is

```
"Replace [hello] with <span class="strong"><p>Awaiting ajax request...</p></span">"
```

Am I missing something here?
Does .replace take "plain text" or will I need to do some regex?

Comment: Replace takes both plain text and regex. What is in newbuffer variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`replace` *returns* a new string with the replacement, it doesn't change the string you call it on.

```
newbuffer = newbuffer.replace( matches[i], p.shortcodes[x].vala );
```

> Does .replace take "plain text" or will I need to do some regex?

You can call `replace` either with a string as the "search" argument, or with a regex. If you give it a string, it will replace the *first* occurrence of that string. If you give it a regex, it will replace the first match, or all matches, depending on whether you include the `g` ("global") flag on the regex.